# Is there a way where we could provide "Read" permissions to a user to a SharePoint Online site using Powershell

Tags: powershell, script, online

I am trying to create a powershell script via SharePoint Online Management Shell, where I will provide "Read" permissions to a user.

Most of the articles I read is that we could only add the user as Site Collection Admin or to a group.

But I only wanted to add the user with "Read" permissions.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You want to add him on site only or library/item?

Comment: I want to add him on site only.

Answer (score 1):

Install PNP module with `Install-Module SharePointPnPPowerShellOnline` and use this command:

```
Set-PnPWebPermission -Url https://company.sp.com/sites/site1 -User 'user@contoso.com' -AddRole 'Read'
```

[Documentation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-pnp/set-pnpwebpermission?view=sharepoint-ps)